# How to keep a counter for rows in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, count

So I have a table lets call it foo and it has a bunch of information in each row, plus a count. What I want is that every time an insert is done on the table, the count variable for each row should be incremented by 1. The thing is that I will have lots of the same rows coming in (which is why I need the count) so I am doing the IGNORE command, because I don't want a huge number of duplicates in my table.

So my insert is something like this:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO foo (blah, blah, count) 
VALUES ("blah", "blah", 1);
```

Now to do the update I am doing a trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER fooCount BEFORE INSERT ON foo
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF (new.blah1=new.blah2 and new.blah1=new.blah2) THEN
    SET new.count=new.count + 1;
  END IF;
END;
```

However, this does not seem to be working. Does anyone have any other suggestions or help on how to do this better?

Comment: Just a point your trigger has `new.blah1=new.blah2` twice. Is this a typo and if not what did you mean to write instead?

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Im not sure that can work in MySql</strike> (edit).

Try to build sql like this:

```
UPDATE Foo
    SET count = count + 1
    WHERE blah1 = 'blah' AND blah2 = "blah2"


IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0 
   BEGIN
      INSERT INTO foo(...) values(...)
   END
```

You will need to modify my code to work in mysql. Here you can read all informations you need:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/if-statement.html

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_row-count

Comment: After thinking about this little longer I wonder if my query was better than that from guy below. Im not sure how concurrency works in mysql - you may need to use table/row locking or something like "queue" with precise timestamps to make that counter correct.

Comment: What I was actually able to figure out was to use this:
INSERT INTO foo(...) values(...) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE count=count+1

And this actually completely handles everything. Even if this isn't actually atomic (i'm not sure if it is) it shouldn't matter, because I'm not looking for a completely precise answer, being off by a few shouldn't be a problem.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score -1):

Just do a simple query before the insert to get the last `Count` Value then your insert should look something like:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO foo (blah, blah, count) VALUES ("blah", "blah", "$lastcount+1");
```

Comment: This is bad idea, because 2 users can insert data in the same time.

Comment: I agree, but this wasn't stated so i was just assuming he was the only doing them :D

Comment: This won't work because I am not the only doing the inserting. Also that would seriously slow my system down.